# Turn anchor value to parent li class

Tags: jquery

I am ofcourse new to jQuery
I am trying trying to get anchor value to turn it's parent li class.

Code i am trying:

```
jQuery('ul.menu').each(function(){
    var turnClass = jQuery(this).find("a").val();
    jQuery('ul.menu li').addClass(turnClass);
});
```

Here is what i want to do:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="about-us"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li class="contact-us"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.val()` is for getting the value of an input element, it can't be used with an anchor. If you want the text inside an anchor, use `.text()`. Then you need your `.each()` loop to process each `li`, not the whole `ul.menu`.

```
jQuery('ul.menu li').each(function() {
    var turnClass = $(this).find('a').text();
    turnClass = turnClass.replace(/ /g, '-').toLowerCase();
    $(this).addClass(turnClass);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should either use `text` or `html` method instead of the `val`,  `val` is used for getting/setting values of form elements.

But it's not the only problem in your script, you should iterate through the `li` elements not the `ul` element. I'd suggest:

```
$('ul.menu > li').addClass(function() {
    return $(this).children('a')
                  .text()
                  .trim()
                  .toLowerCase()
                  .replace(/\s+/g, '-');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/guh1g61d/

Comment: Actually this is something very complicated.
the html code i mentioned above is just for your understanding. 
just think that i have no access to html.

Comment: @Ask4Tec Does this mean that my suggested solution won't work for you? If yes, why didn't you post the "complicated" markup?

Comment: Sorry but you didn't understand what i said.
Thanks for your Suggestion.

Comment: @Ask4Tec You are welcome! I agree, and it seems you didn't understand how the above code works! :)

Comment: @Ask4Tec Well, I just changed the `descendant selector` to `children` so jQuery can select the direct child `a` instead of all the _possible_ `a` descendants. Another difference is just indentation for readability. Effectively, the only (_main_) difference between this solution and Barmar's solution is the `>` selector.

Answer (score 0):

Use .text(), not .val(). .text() grabs any text within an element, .val() gets the value from the 'value' attribute of a form element

Answer (score 0):

You're close. You need to use `text()` to find the anchor text, and `closest()` to find the parent element. You can also search for the `a` tags directly in your initial query.

In the example, I'm also lower-casing the class text and replacing  with `-` as in your example classes.

```js
jQuery('ul.menu a').each(function(){
  var newClass = jQuery(this).text().replace(/\s+/g,'-').toLowerCase();
  jQuery(this).closest('li').addClass(newClass);
});
```

```css
.about-us {
  color: green; 
}

.home {
  color: red;
}

.contact-us {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```